# What are some fun play-by-mail/email games?

Tags: game-recommendation, play-by-post

Me and my friends work office jobs and hence are in front of a computer all day. I thought a fairly slow-paced text game we could play asynchronously  over email throughout the day would be a lot of fun. I'd like games that are either RPGs or collaborative storytelling (I'm not sure how much these overlap), or strategy. They have to be fairly slow-paced, as we'd be playing over the course of a workday. I'm thinking maybe 2-3 'updates' per day, possibly less. We're all new to this type of game, so preferably something that is beginner-friendly. Lastly, it'd be nice if the game emphasized role-playing.

Comment: As written, your question is too broad: we don't know what you like, and just giving you a big list of *every* game that could be played as a PBEM is pointless. You should edit it to say more about your particular needs and preferences. See [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26823/one-off-simple-game-with-little-to-no-character-creation), for example.

Comment: The problem is, even with your edit, there are many, many different games that meet your requirements. You only have to look at a site like rpol.net to see how much variety you can get in that kind of game.

Comment: I don't really know much about PBM gaming, so it's quite difficult for me to narrow the question further. Do you have any suggestions? Also, I didn't know about rpol.net, thanks.

Comment: @Meta Useful information could include: the number of players you're looking to support, ideas about genre or tone you'd like, maybe a mention of something (RPGs you've played, or other media) that inspire you to want to do the PBEM game in the first place.

Comment: Look here http://www.ongoingworlds.com/ or here http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/pbm_list/

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually have any strong requirements that need to be met with expert recommendations (that's what this site specialises in), you just need pointers to directories where you can poke around and see what catches your eye. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that I need directing towards some kind of list or guide that lists some different PBM games, their rules, etc.

Comment: You might want to pop into chat when there's a few people around. Its much easier to discuss and suggest things in there for this type of query